# Student discovers machine that can change the weather and time travel

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to identify a movie that starts with a student or a guy that found a hidden machine that has a ball in the middle. The machine has power to change the weather or go back on time, the film ending with animals or a jungle in the school.

Comment: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086723/?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/180072/time-machine-movie (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 3):

Is it [*My Science Project (1985)*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089652/)?

> A high school student and his friend find a strange, orb-like piece of equipment to use as a science project, but must stop it when it begins to threaten mankind.

[image]

I vaguely recall half the school getting warped into a prehistoric jungle towards the end of the movie, although I am not certain if the other elements fit (I don't remember the orb controlling the weather at all).